# How can we represent the 3 space coordinates uniquely by one point that can be put on a single axis?

Tags: relativity

In the Space-Time diagram (in the rest frame) we often take the Space axis as the horizontal axis and the time axis as the axis perpendicular to it as in the given figure.
[image: plotting of space-time]

While there are other models to graphically represent space-time, my question is:

What function f(x,y,z) on a 3 dimensional surface can we define such that no two distinct points (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) shall have the same value?

i.e f(x1,y1,z1)=f(x2,y2,z2) if and only if x1=x2, y1=y2 and z1=z2

That way every point in the X axis of the figure will represent a unique point in 3-D space.

Comment: You are not suppose to take the figure literally in that way. It is understood that the drawing is a poor substitute for the four-dimensional drawing that would truly represent space-time, and you are suppose to bring enough intuition to understand what is meant.

Comment: That said, there do exist one-to-one and onto mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$, they just fail the smoothness requirements needed to be physical.

Comment: I agree with you. Could you mention the best such mapping? Or a few?